# firebase cloud function error TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined

Tags: android, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm new to firebase cloud function, My situation is Whenever a new article is published in the database, I need to show the notification to my app user.

my code

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');


admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/article/{articleId}')
.onWrite((event: { data: any; }) => {
        var eventSnapshot = event.data;
        var str1 = "Author is ";
        var str = str1.concat(eventSnapshot.child("author").val());
        console.log(str);

        var topic = "android";
        var payload = {
            data: {
                title: eventSnapshot.child("title").val(),
                author: eventSnapshot.child("author").val()
            }
        };


        return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
            .then(function (response: any) {

                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            })
            .catch(function (error: any) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            });
        });
```

Here is my database structure in Firebase.

[image]

And the full Stacktrace from logcat is here.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/srv/lib/index.js:17:41)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

sendNotification
Function execution took 286 ms, finished with status: 'error'
```

Comment: You are working with an old version of the Cloud Functions API.  If you are following a tutorial, it is out of date.  I suggest using the product documentation to learn how it works.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `onWrite()` handler accepts a [Change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.change) object which has `before` & `after` properties, but not `data`. I guess it's the cause of the problem, see `onWrite()` [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.refbuilder#onwrite). If you want to get the updated data use `event.after.child('author')` instead of `event.data.child('author')`.

```js
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/article/{articleId}').onWrite(change => {
  // Exit when the data is deleted.
  if (!change.after.exists()) {
      return null;
  }

  const author = change.after.child('author').val();
  ...
});
```

Comment: @SathishkumarG Glad to help you! Also note that if the document is deleted `change.after` may not exist, so it's better to check it. I updated the answer too.